# Pandas-pivot datafarme

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
         Account                   Product     line_item_product_code             cost
0         AU-LOG                   COMMON              AWSCloudTrail              1
1         AU-STG                   prod1                    AWSGlue               2
2         AU-PRD                   prod2            AWSQueueService               3
3         AU-MGT                   prod3          AWSSecretsManager               4
3         AU-LOG                   prod3          AWSSecretsManager               4
```

I want to visualise the dataframe like this:

```
Account Product   AWSCloudTrail   AWSGlue    AWSQueueService   AWSSecretsManager  s3  KMS  
AU-LOG  COMMON    1                 0           0                   0             0    0
AU-LOG  prod3     0                 0           0                   4             0    0
AU-STG  prod1     0                 2           0                   0             0    0
AU-PRD  prod2     0                 0           3                   0             0    0
AU-MGT  prod3     0                 0           0                   4             0    0
```

How can I achieve this using pandas?

Tried with this, no luck.

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(
        df, values='cost', index=[
            'Account', 'Product'], columns='line_item_product_code',
        fill_value=0)
```

Comment: please show us what you tried to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), as follows:

```
df1 = (df.pivot(['Account', 'Product'], 'line_item_product_code', 'cost')
         .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
         .rename_axis(columns=None)
      ).reset_index()
```

Or use [`.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), as follows:

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index=['Account', 'Product'], columns='line_item_product_code', values='cost', fill_value=0)
         .rename_axis(columns=None)
      ).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df1)


  Account Product  AWSCloudTrail  AWSGlue  AWSQueueService  AWSSecretsManager
0  AU-LOG  COMMON              1        0                0                  0
1  AU-LOG   prod3              0        0                0                  4
2  AU-MGT   prod3              0        0                0                  4
3  AU-PRD   prod2              0        0                3                  0
4  AU-STG   prod1              0        2                0                  0
```